# GORM ssl connection to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, go, ssl, google-cloud-platform, go-gorm

If to check the documentation for GORM Postgres Driver: https://github.com/go-gorm/postgres

it explains the only variant of connection with username and password and

> sslmode=disable

I have a GCP Postgres and need to establish an ssl mode connection with the db.

How to achieve it?

Comment: have you generated certificate and secret key? if you try passing that config as a part of connection string for example `host=localhost port=5432 user=pguser dbname=securitylearning sslmode=verify-full sslrootcert=root.crt sslkey=client.key sslcert=client.crt`